# Can Barbossa be resurrected/saved?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, pirates-of-the-caribbean

In *Pirates of the Caribbean - Dead Men Tell No tales*, Héctor Barbossa kills himself and so he can save his daughter from Salazar. Since he didn’t have time to promote someone to Captain he should be in that "undead" place where Sparrow was after he was eaten by the Kraken.

So logically speaking, Sparrow and his crew (or someone else) just has to go to the end of the world to resurrect/save Barbossa.

Is that correct or did I miss/forgot something?

Comment: I'd imagine it would be hard for him to live either way since he is only alive as of the 2nd movie _per a voodoo curse_ after being killed when the Aztec undead curse was lifted a second after having been shot through the heart. Plus, falling down that Moses-parts-the-seas style trench in the most fucking heroic way imaginable and meeting his end while his child and her lover hang on a chain suspended on a physics-defying ship is probably the single best possible thing that could have happened. No man of honour would _want_ to return after delivering such an awesome, unforgettable exit.

Answer (score 7):

To bring someone back for land of the living, one should be in the Davy Jones's locker. Jack was there, that's why his crew traveled to end of the world to bring him back. 
We can't say for sure that Barbossa ended up in the same place as Jack did. Or since all the curses/bindings etc are broken since the trident, we can't say whether there's Davy Jones's locker, and/or whether can people go there. Usually there needs to be someone (currently Will Turner), that decides one would go there or not. He is the current captain on the Flying Dutchman, who also had the control over the locker.

So we cannot say for sure that Barbossa ended up in the same place as Jack did, and so we can't say for sure that just by traveling end of the world do the trick, there could be more preparation other than we've seen in the movie.

*Since he didn’t have time to promote someone to Captain he should be in that "undead" place...*

Pirates doesn't work that way. Sailors can obtain ranks out of the usual rule-book. (they're pirates). But, Jack **still** is a captain. Either him or someone else would rise up to the rank of captain in Barbossa's ship. There's also their own guideline too(Pirate Code). so either following that or by mutiny,or by getting other sailors support or any other way, someone can become the captain. Barbossa doesn't need to promote someone, although he can. but we can't be sure that other sailors will follow him/her.

Comment: I think there might be a chance that he’s alive because the curses seemed broken/not working  to me after the trident broke. As seen in the post credit scene there still is a „tentacle man“ by will Turner’s bed side which shouldn’t be possible because all curses should be broken with the trident. Just like Salazar’s curse Wills curse should be broken and he should be allowed to walk on land without getting a tentacle face(I now that it isn’t quite final that will gets a tentacle face but it seems so in the post creature scene).

Comment: Actually Will shouldn’t be alive right now because they removed his heart from his body after him killing Davy Jones. With all curses removed there shouldn’t be anything keeping will alive right now.

Comment: @LukasSokcevic We don't know how curses are lifted. So maybe when it happened, Will might got his heart back, or he got the ability to live without it somehow. But in real world, what you said makes sense, big time. Hopefully, these will get answered in the next movie

Comment: I think there is one and only one factor that determines if Barbossa can be resurrected, and that's if Geoffrey Rush is still alive and looking for a paycheck the next time they decide to make a Pirates of the Caribbean movie.